# Excel the INDEX MATCH function returns #VALUE

Tags: excel

I would like to use the INDEX/MATCH function with a correlation to the external workbook.
[image]

but it keeps throwing #VALUE regardless of the formula

```
 =INDEX('[Master PAYE Costs.xlsx]Project 494'!$D$3:$D$100,MATCH((B2,'[Master PAYE Costs.xlsx]Project 494'!$AA$3:$AA$100),0))
```

The data range on the external workbook is between rows 3 and 100.

What I did do wrong here?

Comment: I suspect you meant to use: `=INDEX('[Master PAYE Costs.xlsx]Project 494'!$D$3:$D$100,MATCH(B2,'[Master PAYE Costs.xlsx]Project 494'!$AA$3:$AA$100,0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you added too many parenthesis ().

So I changed the formula from this:

MATCH( **->** (B2,'[Master PAYE Costs.xlsx]Project 494'!$AA$3:$AA$100) **<-** ,0)

`=INDEX('[Master PAYE Costs.xlsx]Project 494'!$D$3:$D$100,MATCH((B2,'[Master PAYE Costs.xlsx]Project 494'!$AA$3:$AA$100),0))`

To this:

MATCH( **->** B2,'[Master PAYE Costs.xlsx]Project 494'!$AA$3:$AA$100 **<-** ,0)

`=INDEX('[Master PAYE Costs.xlsx]Project 494'!$D$3:$D$100,MATCH(B2,'[Master PAYE Costs.xlsx]Project 494'!$AA$3:$AA$100,0))`

Hope this helps!

Kind regards,